# Postfix Failed to start : unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: postfix, centos7

Postfix was running well untill I decided for some reason to restart since I updated **message_size_limit**

By doing this

> postconf -e message_size_limit=24840000

Stopped it and Now ...
Postfix wont start , It keeps on saying

> fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable

I tried reverting the change but no luck,

```
Sep 23 20:47:45 example.com systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Sep 23 20:47:45 example.com postfix/postfix-script[13392]: starting the Postfix mail system
Sep 23 20:47:45 example.com postfix/master[13394]: fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temporarily unavailable
Sep 23 20:47:46 example.com postfix/master[13393]: fatal: daemon initialization failure
Sep 23 20:47:47 example.com postfix/postfix-script[13395]: fatal: mail system startup failed
Sep 23 20:47:47 example.com systemd[1]: postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 23 20:47:47 example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Sep 23 20:47:47 example.com systemd[1]: Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
Sep 23 20:47:47 example.com systemd[1]: postfix.service failed.
```

If it would **help** , I also installed SSL from **LetsEncrypt** like 2 weeks ago , perhaps that might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Google says: http://www.math.ias.edu/~tarzadon/pages/posts/postfix-master-dead-but-pid-file-exists-112.php Did you see that?

Comment: _Thanks for the URL ,_ Not exactly the `same problem` but it helped to arrive there , Deserved the down vote

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to to the **[URL](http://www.math.ias.edu/%7Etarzadon/pages/posts/postfix-master-dead-but-pid-file-exists-112.php)** shared with **[@ryan-babchishin](https://serverfault.com/users/313604/ryan-babchishin)** , it helped to arrive to the solution

##The Problem
So I was using **systemctl** to start,reload,stop postfix and it was adding other hidden users , I recently updated **virtualmin** , and it keeps on using

```
#systemctl status postfix.service
#systemctl stop postfix.service
#systemctl start postfix.service
```

Instead of

```
#postfix <start/stop>
```

##The Solution
So it resulted the **master.lock** being used by other users hence we can not modify , resulting to

> fatal: mail system startup failed

We only need to **kill the process** and **start postfix**

Now ... Check to see if the file is there

```
#ls -l /var/lib/postfix/master.lock
```

Look for the process utilizing it

```
#htop
```

or simply do

```
#fuser /var/lib/postfix/master.lock
7881
```

Now

```
#ps -ef | grep 7881
root      7881     1  0 Sep16 ?        00:00:09 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
postfix   9127  7881  0 10:04 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t unix -u
postfix   9469  7881  0 10:13 ?        00:00:00 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
postfix   9470  7881  0 10:13 ?        00:00:00 proxymap -t unix -u
postfix   9471  7881  0 10:13 ?        00:00:00 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
postfix   9472  7881  0 10:13 ?        00:00:00 anvil -l -t unix -u
postfix   9476  7881  0 10:13 ?        00:00:00 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
root      9486  8671  0 10:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 7881
postfix  28581  7881  0 Sep17 ?        00:00:01 qmgr -l -t unix -u
```

Find the Process that uses the lock file

Kill the Process

```
#kill 7881
```

Now lets get back to postfix

```
# postfix status
postfix/postfix-script: the Postfix mail system is not running
```

Now start it

```
# postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
```

Postfix is running again!

Let me play [Sticky Bubble on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fadsel.stickybubble) to relax a bit :)