# Postfix failed because it can't set an exclusive lock

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server

I'm trying to make a Postfix-based E-mail server.
I face the following error whenever I try to launch the server:

```
Sep 24 12:17:39 hostname9727 postfix/postfix-script[7506]: warning: group or other writable: /etc/postfix/./master.cf
Sep 24 12:17:39 hostname9727 postfix/postfix-script[7507]: warning: group or other writable: /etc/postfix/./relocated
Sep 24 12:17:39 hostname9727 postfix/postfix-script[7508]: warning: group or other writable: /etc/postfix/./generic
Sep 24 12:17:39 hostname9727 postfix/postfix-script[7524]: starting the Postfix mail system
Sep 24 12:17:39 hostname9727 postfix/master[7526]: fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: unable to set exclusive lock: Resource temp...vailable
Sep 24 12:17:40 hostname9727 postfix/master[7525]: fatal: daemon initialization failure
Sep 24 12:17:41 hostname9727 postfix/postfix-script[7527]: fatal: mail system startup failed
Sep 24 12:17:41 hostname9727 systemd[1]: postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 24 12:17:41 hostname9727 systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Sep 24 12:17:41 hostname9727 systemd[1]: Unit postfix.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

postconf -M

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases home_mailbox = /home/virtual/mail/
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = /home/virtual/mail/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = hostname9727.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/24
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

what is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the lock file?

Comment: There was a post very recently about a similar problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/804993/postfix-failed-to-start-unable-to-set-exclusive-lock-resource-temporarily-una?noredirect=1#comment1021539_804993

Comment: In that case, could you please either answer your own question or mark it as duplicate of the other one?

Comment: The answer is here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/804993/postfix-failed-to-start-unable-to-set-exclusive-lock-resource-temporarily-una?noredirect=1#comment1021539_804993
Thanks Ryan Babchishin